# 'AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, adal, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I'm having trouble when authenticating a user with it's Microsoft Account. I'm using OpenId Connect Authentication, but when I call the AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync method, i get the following message.

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.

The auth options are the following ones:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions => 
        {
            openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            openIdOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            openIdOptions.Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}", "common", "/v2.0");
            openIdOptions.ClientId = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientId"];
            openIdOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientSecret"];
            openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            openIdOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
                ValidateIssuer = false
            };
            var scopes = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:Scopes"].Split(' ');
                foreach (string scope in scopes){
                    openIdOptions.Scope.Add(scope);
            }
            openIdOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents{
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                {   
                    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                    var identifier = context.Principal.Claims.First(item => item.Type == ObjectIdentifierType).Value;
                    IMemoryCache memoryCache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
                    var result = await GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(identifier, code, memoryCache);
                    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                },
            };
        });
```

And this is how my GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync looks like this (I know it's not pretty, just trying to make it work):

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(string userId, string code, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();
        try
        {
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token/", userTokenCache);
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientId"], Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientSecret"]);
            string[] scope = new List<String>().Append("https://graph.windows.net").ToArray();
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,new Uri(Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:RedirectUri"]), credential, Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ResourceId"]);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have no idea of what could be causing the error. I can use the authorization code if i send a postman request, but I'm still not able to add the resource id in that request.

I've registered the app in Microsoft's Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` libraryto acquire the access token. This library is used for the Azure AD app which register on the Azure portal instead of Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.

To acquire the token for the Azure AD V2.0 apps, we can use the [MSAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/1.1.0-preview) library. And here is the code sample for your reference:

```
OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
{
    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
        new ConfidentialClientApplication(Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"], Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"]+ "signin-oidc", new ClientCredential(Configuration["AzureAD:Secret"]), null, null);
    var result =await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,new string[]{"user.read"});
    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks you so much for your help. I've managed to install the MSAL package, buy now I'm having trouble with the scopes.
Im getting the following message:"AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope."
I thought it might have to do with the scopes defined in the CCA, but when i add them to the var result line, i get the same problem. The scopes are defined in the Application Registration Portal though, so I dont really know what the problem is

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to make it work. I can now authenticate my user with OpenId Connect, no problems with that. Had to add openid, profile and offline_access scopes in the app portal. Now I'm having trouble making it work with the Graph package. Should I make another question or give more details here?

Comment: For the different question, I suggest that you reopen a new thread so the community could recognize the issue more easily. And if this post is helpful for the orignal issue, you can accept this as answer. And other community who have the same issue could search the issue get help from this thread easily:)